# Npgsql query with search variable parameter returning empty result C# Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am using Npgsql to query a database table and show the results on my page/view. *The code works fine WITHOUT the where clause and parameters as it gets all the rows from the table onto the view.* Now I am trying to incoporate a search string variable (if the user types in the string, then give me the table records that contain this string). My code is as follows

```
string searchValue = TempData["String"].ToString();

var model = new List<ProductViewModel>();      

NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection
     ("Host=192.168.0.52;Database=test;Username=test;Password=test");
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand
     ("SELECT * FROM q_product WHERE q_description like @string", connection);

        //lets include our paramater
cmd.Parameters.Add("@string", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text);
cmd.Parameters["@string"].Value = searchValue;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(searchValue);

NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    var prod = new ProductViewModel();
    prod.q_description = dr["q_description"].ToString();
    prod.q_barcode = dr["q_barcode"].ToString();               

    model.Add(prod);  
}

var pagedProduct = new PaginatedSearch<ProductViewModel>(model, pageIndex, pageSize);

return View(pagedProduct);
```

Records are returned fine when I only have

```
SELECT * FROM q_product
```

but after including the where clause and my search string variable, I am getting an empty page. What am I doing wrong in my code for this?

Comment: What is the contents of `searchValue`? Also take a look at the documentation for [`LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: on debugging searchValue is always whatever text I have typed in the searchbox (which is the expected behaviour). Its just skipping the while loop and going straight to the pagedProduct when where clause is added. I will have a look at documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [like statement for npgsql using parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950279/like-statement-for-npgsql-using-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `%` in your query to make use of the [like](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) operator.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand
     ("SELECT * FROM q_product WHERE q_description like '%' || @string || '%'", connection);
```

Comment: I had that exact line before, with the exact same empty result.

Comment: The missing `%` was what I was getting at. You could try to run the same query against the database manually, without your c# layer in between, and check if there's a result there.

Comment: updated with proper concatenation & auto parameter quoting

Comment: thanks for the assist @JGH and 0xCAFEBABE. The concatenation fix solved my problem, and I am getting the desired functionality now. Cheers.